# How does a dual-wattage (automotive) bulb work?

Tags: automotive, lamp, watts

I have a motorcycle headlamp bulb on my desk here. I notice the bulb has a rating of "60/55W" and has three connectors instead of the usual two.

Evidently these correspond to the high/low beam setting respectively but how does it work in practice? Are there two separate filaments within the bulb - one 55W and one 60W - that can be turned on either individually or together?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar set-up is used on some vehicles for rear lights. One filament for position light and one for stop light.

Comment: I noticed this on my bike rack today! I was interested in why but didn't have the time to form the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply has two filaments, you should be able to see both of them. The lower power one is for the dipped beam, and is positioned to give a low beam.

Comment: In my old car, it was one or the other.  I could light both at the same time by holding the high-beam lever back, though.